# weird response from funding an accnount on testnet

Tags: horizon, testnet, new-developer

Following the tutorial and using stellar-base, I created an account and successfully generated a keypair, as follows:

New key pair created!
Account ID:   ****
Secret: ****

I then tried to fund the account using friendbot, but got an unexpected response like this:

{
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions/3a298a347189e917ee4e557944df31c111fb13cfae4ef1b12de4b7a7c87f68be"
},
"account": {
"href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GDZE7JPWK64U3N4M3SEFUT736DT5R4UFAE74EMQGDLJXXUFHRHNWBN6M"
},
"ledger": {
"href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/ledgers/653648"
},
"operations": {
"href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions/3a298a347189e917ee4e557944df31c111fb13cfae4ef1b12de4b7a7c87f68be/operations{?cursor,limit,order}",
"templated": true
},
"effects": {
"href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions/3a298a347189e917ee4e557944df31c111fb13cfae4ef1b12de4b7a7c87f68be/effects{?cursor,limit,order}",
"templated": true
},
"precedes": {
"href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions?order=asc\u0026cursor=2807396783099904"
},
"succeeds": {
"href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions?order=desc\u0026cursor=2807396783099904"
},
"transaction": {
"href": "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions/3a298a347189e917ee4e557944df31c111fb13cfae4ef1b12de4b7a7c87f68be"
}
},
"id": "3a298a347189e917ee4e557944df31c111fb13cfae4ef1b12de4b7a7c87f68be",
"paging_token": "2807396783099904",
"successful": true,
"hash": "3a298a347189e917ee4e557944df31c111fb13cfae4ef1b12de4b7a7c87f68be",
"ledger": 653648,
"created_at": "2022-10-24T03:30:38Z",
"source_account": "GDZE7JPWK64U3N4M3SEFUT736DT5R4UFAE74EMQGDLJXXUFHRHNWBN6M",
"source_account_sequence": "1885490643086",
"fee_account": "GDZE7JPWK64U3N4M3SEFUT736DT5R4UFAE74EMQGDLJXXUFHRHNWBN6M",
"fee_charged": "100",
"max_fee": "1000000",
"operation_count": 1,
"envelope_xdr": "AAAAAgAAAADyT6X2V7lNt4zciFpP+/Dn2PKFAT/CMgYa03vQp4nbYAAPQkAAAAG3AAAAjgAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAABAAAAABB90WssODNIgi6BHveqzxTRmIpvAFRyVNM+Hm2GVuCcAAAAAAAAAADNCEI4Ef9DSN34CE7xCgjSy92mN4K9bqMHnWeiL94nTgAAABdIdugAAAAAAAAAAAKnidtgAAAAQIOBiJ11T8xvHfQwvRtGzo+Nc5f3cfhkRfMkLR7z4aKMHs9r3ECq389uHbkeCtQvTlMIgCIaKgIDeNoJR9teqQSGVuCcAAAAQJTpkU7WSBf3gp57H4MTMilAsVg/tYBdXvnDA2c7SQEcP/u5G+mLiIikBl834cJb7C3FpIKO3Km5fWCGSXb7yQc=",
"result_xdr": "AAAAAAAAAGQAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
"result_meta_xdr": "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",
"fee_meta_xdr": "AAAAAgAAAAMACddkAAAAAAAAAADyT6X2V7lNt4zciFpP+/Dn2PKFAT/CMgYa03vQp4nbYAAAAAA7HRcYAAABtwAAAI0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAAAAAAAJ12QAAAAAY1VUrQAAAAAAAAABAAn5UAAAAAAAAAAA8k+l9le5TbeM3IhaT/vw59jyhQE/wjIGGtN70KeJ22AAAAAAOx0WtAAAAbcAAACNAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAACddkAAAAAGNVVK0AAAAA",
"memo_type": "none",
"signatures": [
"g4GInXVPzG8d9DC9G0bOj41zl/dx+GRF8yQtHvPhoowez2vcQKrfz24duR4K1C9OUwiAIhoqAgN42glH216pBA==",
"lOmRTtZIF/eCnnsfgxMyKUCxWD+1gF1e+cMDZztJARw/+7kb6YuIiKQGXzfhwlvsLcWkgo7cqbl9YIZJdvvJBw=="
],
"valid_after": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"preconditions": {
"timebounds": {
"min_time": "0"
}
}
}

---

The expected json response may look like:

{
"hash": "ed9e96e136915103f5d8978cbb2036628e811f2c59c4c3d88534444cf504e360",
"result": "received",
"submission_result": "000000000000000a0000000000000001000000000000000000000000"
}

---

I truly don't know how to fix it. Any advice and help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The transaction has succeeded.
With the transaction you are trying to make an account using an non existing source account you have to use Friendbot account or another active account as source account for the transaction and you will always get this type of response as this is sent from horizon server.

You can parse this further and make a custom response but as far as horizon response is concerned without making changes to core source code and running this on private you cant make the response custom to your need

To fund the account using the friendbot account use the following url with addr parameter with your generated accound id as value

https://friendbot.stellar.org/?addr=YOUR_GENERATED_ACCOUNT_ID

or you can use [Stellar Laboratory](https://laboratory.stellar.org/#account-creator?network=test)